# Replace standard Vaadin radiobutton icon with custom one

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

All standard HTML components like radiobuttons or checkboxes are slightly modified within Vaadin's themes. The question is сan I modify them in the way i want by overriding Vaadin's standard ones? For example, replace radiobutton's icon with my own picture. 
Is it possible and if it is, how can I achieve it (for some reason I can't make individual component for each case)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the visuals for the radio buttons, as well as all other components.

For this, you create a new theme and put your new/additional definitions for the radio button in your sass file.

[Here](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/themes/themes-valo.html) is the documentation on how to do this.
The radiobutton style in valo is defined [this](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#mixin-valo-radiobutton-style) way, via a mixin.

Comment: That's a good start, for sure, but it doesn't answer the question.